# javascript/WebSQL: how to cancel query

Tags: javascript, sql, web-sql

I have this situation in which I execute a complex query which will take some time. But sometimes I don't need the result anymore, so I would like to cancel it. Is this possible?
Here is the basic structure:

```
db.transaction(
    function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ...JOIN ...', [a,b,c], callback) ;
    } 
    , function(err) { .... }
    , function() { /* transaction completed */ }
) ;
```

Comment: According to the spec I'm not seeing any option to cancel a running query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No abort in WebSQL API. Suggested method invoke invalid SQL to the active transaction that you want to abort and rollback, as follow is:

```
var errback = {
  return true; // rollback
}
tx.executeSql('ABORT', [], null, errback); // yes, this will cause error
```